# Drupal 7 remotely get node article/content via API

Tags: drupal

I'd like to get a specific node/content type and display the HTML remotly in another application.

Is this something that D7 supports or has an API module for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using Drupal Services Module. Create a webservice and transfer data via web service and consume it at other application end, and display as you want.
 https://www.drupal.org/project/services